# BuddyPress/WordPress extension for social networking

Tags: wordpress, extensibility, buddypress

I am currently constructing a social networking website for a friend of mine.  I was going to write this from scratch using PHP, javascript, ect... But it seems as though a lot of the stuff I am doing is reinventing the wheel.  Poorly at that.  I am currently looking around to see if there is a framework or API that will do all the basic stuff (that has already been through years of best-practice revisions and so forth) but still extensible enough for me to customize it easily to my friends liking.  I put my ear to the ground (code for searching google) and somehow or the other BuddyPress-which is an extension to wordpress seems to pop up quite a bit.  But it strikes me as more of a blogging sort of thing.  Plus, Looking to extend the functionality of this looks to be a herculean task.

One functionality piece that I am trying to add is the ability for the user to have a split account.  Let's say that a user joins my site, he will have a profile that only certain users can see, but at the same time, he will have an account that only other people can see.  Is that the level of extensibility that I can add to Buddy Press.  That functionality is basically on the database back-end.  So you would think that that would be simple.  Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress and Buddypress are certainly very extensible! If you're comparing writing a social network from scratch with writing a plugin/extension for Buddypress, it's almost no contest -- writing for WP/BP is definitely more straightforward. Plus, since you're building on top of (usually) thoroughly-tested code, I would suggest that you take a crack at it.

As per your specific use case, it's curious, could you add more information about why and how the user will interact with their "split" profile?

If I were going to code something like this, after I set up WP/BP, I would create extra profile fields for users -- e.g. alternate_bio -- and your plugin can load these profile fields IF the user viewing them has the appropriate credentials.

For learning to write the plugin, I'd start here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey Felix.  Thanks for the reply.  The way the site is going to operate is when a user registers, he will have a personal side, and a business side.  When he add friends, those friend will either be personal contacts or business contacts.  Those friends will not be able to see posts, friends, pages if they are not in the correct group.  Sounds a little complex, but I am thinking it can be done.  If you have any ideas I would appreciate it.  Thx